# How to improve my tree in Lyx

Tags: lyx, forest, trees

In Lyx, I created a tree using forest. However, as you can see from picture 2, it is not a very nice tree. Could you please help me? I would have liked to rotate the tree horizontally.

```
\begin{forest}
[\emph{Corpora}, fit=band
[Generalità[generali][specialistici]][Modalità[lingua scritta][lingua orale][misti]][Cronologia[sincronico][diacronico]][Lingua[monolingue][bilingue[paralleli][comparabili]]][Integrità[testi interi][porzioni di testi]]]
\end{forest}
```

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Comment: Welcome! The biggest improvement will be if you add a complete code and not a screen shot of an incomplete code to your question. Otherwise you may risk getting a screenshot of an incomplete code as answer. ;-)

Comment: You're right! done! is it ok?

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2):

You probably load `forest` with the `linguistics` option. If you remove this option, the tree becomes nicer IMHO.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest} % remove [linguistics]
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={edge={semithick}},
%forked edges
[\emph{Corpora}, fit=band
 [Generalit\`a
  [generali]
  [specialistici]
 ]
 [Modalit\`a
  [lingua scritta]
  [lingua orale]
  [misti]
 ]
 [Cronologia
  [sincronico]
  [diacronico]
 ]
 [Lingua
  [monolingue]
  [bilingue
   [paralleli]
   [comparabili]
  ]
 ]
 [Integrit\`a
  [testi interi]
  [porzioni di testi]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment `forked edges` you get

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!